# Como vincular un chekedListBox con un reportviewer reconociendo todos los items seleccionados?

Tags: c#

este es el boton que genera el informe:

```
 private void bunifuThinButton21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                      
    {
        Datos datos = new Datos();
        AsesoriaFiscal af = new AsesoriaFiscal();

        datos.Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
        datos.Nif = txtNifCif.Text;
        datos.Direccion = txtDireccion.Text;
        datos.Poblacion = txtPoblacion.Text;
        datos.Provincia = txtProvincia.Text;
        datos.CodigoPostal = txtCodigoPostal.Text;
        datos.Telefono = txtTelefono.Text;
        datos.Email = txtEmail.Text;
        datos.Actividades = Actividad.Text;

        af.datos.Add(datos);
        af.Show();           
    }
```

Y esta es la class Datos:

```
   namespace Operaciones
 {
       public class Datos
   {
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Nif { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Poblacion { get; set; }
    public string Provincia { get; set; }
    public string CodigoPostal { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Actividades { get; set; }
    }
   }
```

Todo esto es correcto.
Pero cuando lo intento con un chekedlistbox, solamente reconoce un item (los chekedlistbox son todos los que empiezan por chlb:

```
    private void bunifuThinButton21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SeguridadDatos datos1 = new SeguridadDatos();
        InformeSeguridad ag = new InformeSeguridad();


        datos1.SeguridadFisica = chlbSeguridadFisicaInstalaciones.SelectedItem.ToString();
        datos1.DescripcionDeLosSistemas = chlbDescripcionSistemas.CheckedItems.ToString();
        datos1.ServidorDedicado = chlbServidorDedicado.CheckedItems.ToString();
        datos1.ServidorNoDedicado = chlbServidorNoDedicado.CheckedItems.ToString();
        datos1.OrdenadoresPersonales = chlbOrdenadoresPersonales.CheckedItems.ToString();
        datos1.ServidorCorreoElectronico = chlbServidorCorreoElectronico.CheckedItems.ToString();
        datos1.ServidorPaginaWeb = chlbServidorPaginaWeb.CheckedItems.ToString();
        datos1.EquiposInformaticos = chlbEquiposInformaticos.CheckedItems.ToString();


        ag.informe.Add(datos1);
        ag.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Hola, ¿de donde sale `datos.Nombre`? Creo que deberías añadir más código para que alguien pueda orientarte de manera más acertada.

Comment: SeguridadDatos datos = new SeguridadDatos();

Comment: y viene de una clase: public string Nombre { get; set; }

Comment: Entonces hace falta también saber qué es eso de `SeguridadDatos`, ya que no sabemos qué propiedades tiene esa clase.

Comment: Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y añadas todo el código necesario para que se pueda seguir de forma clara la lógica de tu programa y que es cada cosa, si no es muy difícil poder ayudarte.

Comment: Por partes. La propiedad de `CheckedListBox` `SelectedItem` sólo contiene un elemento. De todas maneras, si usas un control de ese tipo imagino que a lo que quieres acceder es a `CheckedItems`. Pero luego hay otro problema. De ninguna manera vas a poder asignar a un string (`Nombre`) una coleccion de items. Resumiendo, creo que no tienes claro que hacer, y mucho menos lo tenemos nosotros si no amplias la información de manera sustancial.

Comment: Si pongo CheckedItems , en el informe sale: System.Form.....

Comment: Y que esperas que te salga? Estas intentando asignar una colección de objetos a un string. Que es lo que quieres que salga en el informe? Los items seleccionados en el CheckdListBox separados por comas? o en una tabla?

Comment: en forma de lista

Comment: Eso imaginaba. Y como esperas que salga en forma de lista usando un string `Nombre`? Para eso, en tu report deberías tener alguna estructura que soportase listas y asignar correctamente los datos. Me temo que es demasiado amplia tu pregunta, lo siento :)

Comment: Para probar como queda sin cambiar el reporte, puedes usar algo como lo siguiente: `datos1.SeguridadFisica = String.Join("\n", chlbSeguridadFisicaInstalaciones.CheckedItems.Cast<String>());` (siempre y cuando, los items que has añadido a tus checkedLists sean de tipo string.

Comment: gracias a todos por vuestra paciencia, es la primera vez que estoy en este foro y no estoy muy suelto

Comment: Pikoh, gracias por tu último comentario funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te vale con que aparezcan todos los items con el check activado separados con un retorno de carro, puedes utilizar lo siguiente:

```
datos1.SeguridadFisica = String.Join("\n", chlbSeguridadFisicaInstalaciones.CheckedItems.Cast<String>());
```

Esto une los items con el check activado usando `\n` que es un retorno de carro.

Si ya necesitas que aparezcan en una tabla, debes cambiar el report para intrducir dicha tabla y tendrías que pasar los items en alguna estructura, por ejemplo un DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que entiendo es que necesitas obtener la lista de aquellos Datos que estan checkeados:

```
//Lista auxiliar donde introduciras solo los items seleccionados
List<Datos> listaChecked = new List<Datos>(); 

//loop de 0 hasta la longitud de tu checkedlistbox
for(int i=0 ; i<checkedListBox1.Items.Count ; i++){
    //Va item a item comprobando que el estado sea checked
    if(checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        //Si está checkeado añade a la lista
        listaChecked.add(checkedListBox.Items[i]);
    }
}
```

Y luego añades listaChecked al reportViewer. Si tienes dudas con esto último necesito la parte del código referente a añadir los datos al reportViewer.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien esta respuesta. Si ya tienes los items seleccionados en `CheckedItems`, de que sirve generar una lista y añadirlos ahi?

Comment: public partial class InformeSeguridad : Form
    {
       public List<SeguridadDatos> informe = new List<SeguridadDatos>();

        public InformeSeguridad()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InformeSeguridad_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            reportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", informe));
            this.reportViewer2.RefreshReport();
        }

    }